# SSRS expression to get first character from string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am having a field with string values as `"First Middle Last"` and i want to show the initial characters from this string as `"FML"`

how can i do it in terms of ssrs expression ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the field `MyString` always has 3 words the following will find the first character of the First, Second and Last words.  This admittedly doesn't handle instances where there are more or less than 3 words, but hopefully should get you started if you require more finesse.

```
=Left(Fields!MyString.Value, 1) + " " +
 Left(Mid(Fields!MyString.Value, InStr(Fields!MyString.Value, " ") + 1), 1) + " " +
 Left(Mid(Fields!MyString.Value, InStrRev(Fields!MyString.Value, " ") + 1), 1)
```

**Edit**

To cope with the possiblity of only two words (as suggested in the commetns below) a check for the index of the spaces could be used to ensure that they are not the same, and thus 3 words exist.  This would make the code as follows

```
=Left(Fields!MyString.Value, 1) + " " +
 Left(Mid(Fields!MyString.Value, InStr(Fields!MyString.Value, " ") + 1), 1) +
 iif(InStrRev(Fields!MyString.Value, " ") > InStr(Fields!MyString.Value, " "),
   " " + Left(Mid(Fields!MyString.Value, InStrRev(Fields!MyString.Value, " ") + 1), 1),
   "")
```

Comment: `MyString` can have 2 fields

Comment: Edited for two words (which is what I assume you meant by "2 fields")